# Slice function in .csv

Tags: javascript

I have a .csv file that I am pulling into d3 and transforming to work for my assignment. I have one column that has the elements as percentages "xx.x%". I would like to remove the percentage sign, so that I am left with just "xx.x" for each element in that column. I know the slice() function needs to be used, and that I will be taking the values from 1 - length-2, but I'm not sure how to write the function. I'll include the other cleanup code so that you can get a feel for the file I'm working with. Thank you!!

```
    function cleanup(raw_data) {
        // remove unneeded columns

        var data = [];

        raw_data.forEach(function(obj){
        if (obj["County"] == "Dutchess" && obj["Month"] == 12)
            data.push(obj)
            });

        data.forEach(function(obj) {
          delete obj["2012 Census Population"];
          delete obj["Population 18+ Estimate"];
          delete obj["OPO"];
          delete obj["Location"];
          delete obj["Month"];
          delete obj["County"];
          delete obj["Chart Month"];
        });
    data.sort(function (a,b) {
        return a["Year"] > b["Year"];
    }); 

    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
    data.forEach(function(obj) {
      obj["yourCol"] = obj["yourCol"].slice(0, -1);
    });
```